# Use Synology NAS as public upload folder

Tags: file-sharing, synology

For a loose (once-only) company, I would like to create a public folder on a Synology NAS (latest DSM installed). It's features should be:
- it is accessible with an URL
- it is accessible without a password
- anyone (with the URL) can upload
- once uploaded, nobody can delete files or folders

Would this be possible? Synology documentation doesn't say a lot about this. Hope you can help.

Comment: This question is probably better located at superuser. That being said, it should be possible. Accessible by URL--->enable WebDAV. No password--->make account without password, or use guest. Upload, but no delete--->edit shared folder, check "special permissions" box, then check "write" and uncheck "delete" in the window that opens.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Damon. That fixes a couple of things. Most important part of the setup should be that there is no login. Just like you can do with a shared file links: you can see a folder with it contents and download directly without credentials. I would like to create the same for uploading files. You think that would be possible on a Synology NAS?

Comment: I wouldn't know (never tried, and won't try because unauthenticated access, even more so write access, is a huge security issue). It should be possible, though... I know anon FTP is explicitly supported, and you can do iSCSI anonymously too. Would have to try.